# Datediff to find difference in break time

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I have a query that pulls runs a function to grab employee punch in information.  It pulls the time segments, combines them for the specific day, and they runs a check to see

1) who did not take a break that day
2) who took a break less than 30 minutes

The first part of this works correctly.  It displays the 7 people for the week who did not take a break (all have a break of 0 minutes).  However, it does not display the one user who ONLY took a 22 minute break.  I believe what is happening, is it's not fully combining all the time clock information for the specific day.  It's only combining the information for those who did NOT take a break. Any help?

My Query is:

```
    SELECT        lEmployeeID, NUM_Hours, CASE WHEN tmp.Break_Time_Minutes < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Break_Time_Minutes END AS Break_Time_Minutes, 
                         CASE WHEN tmp.Break_Time_Minutes < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SkippedBreak, sFirstName, sLastName, TotalHours
FROM            (SELECT        employee.lEmployeeID, employee.sFirstName, employee.sLastName, employee.TotalHours, ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, employee.dtTimeIn, 
                                                    employee.dtTimeOut) / 60.0 / 60.0), 1) AS NUM_Hours, DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(employee.dtTimeOut), MAX(employee.dtTimeIn)) AS Break_Time_Minutes
                          FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS employee LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    Employees AS e ON employee.lEmployeeID = e.lEmployeeID
                          WHERE        (employee.TotalHours >= 0) AND (employee.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                                                    (employee.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (employee.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
                          GROUP BY employee.lEmployeeID, employee.sLastName, employee.sFirstName, employee.TotalHours, CAST(employee.dtTimeIn AS Datetime)) AS tmp
WHERE        (NUM_Hours > 6) AND (Break_Time_Minutes < 30)
```

Comment: your query is un-neccessary complicated.in your last post i suggested to in your exisitng query(last post),create one more column in same query with datediff and show .do same now.no need of group by or sum.

Comment: I have to combine the segments... I only want to report those who have taken a break less than 30 minutes, including those who didn't take one at all.  I also need to report the total number of hours they worked without an adequate break

Comment: first you create one more column in same query with datediff after this you do combine work and sum work using GROUP BY employee.lEmployeeID only.thatswhy i am telling to show your last post query which was simple .

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the query helps me understand it.

The problem seems to be in the calculation of the break time.  How are both of these calculations accurate?

```
         ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, employee.dtTimeIn, 
                            employee.dtTimeOut) / 60.0 / 60.0), 1) AS NUM_Hours,
         DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(employee.dtTimeIn), MAX(employee.dtTimeOut)
                 ) AS Break_Time_Minutes
```

The second is calculating the break time as the minimum of the time in and the max of the time out.  Presumably, this is the total time the employee is there.

Perhaps you mean:

```
      MIN(DATEDIFF(mi, employee.dtTimeIn, employee.dtTimeOut)
         ) AS Break_Time_Minutes
```

The full formatted query is:

```
SELECT lEmployeeID, NUM_Hours,
       (CASE WHEN tmp.Break_Time_Minutes < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Break_Time_Minutes
        END) AS Break_Time_Minutes, 
       (CASE WHEN tmp.Break_Time_Minutes < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS SkippedBreak,
       sFirstName, sLastName, TotalHours
FROM (SELECT employee.lEmployeeID, employee.sFirstName, employee.sLastName, 
             employee.TotalHours,
             ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, employee.dtTimeIn, 
                                employee.dtTimeOut) / 60.0 / 60.0), 1) AS NUM_Hours,
             DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(employee.dtTimeIn), MAX(employee.dtTimeOut)
                     ) AS Break_Time_Minutes
      FROM dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList
                        ) employee LEFT OUTER JOIN
           Employees e
           ON employee.lEmployeeID = e.lEmployeeID
      WHERE (employee.TotalHours >= 0) AND (employee.DID IS NOT NULL) OR
            (employee.DID IS NOT NULL) AND (employee.dtTimeOut IS NULL)
      GROUP BY employee.lEmployeeID, employee.sLastName, employee.sFirstName,
               employee.TotalHours, CAST(employee.dtTimeIn AS Datetime)
     ) tmp
WHERE (NUM_Hours > 6) AND (Break_Time_Minutes < 30)
```

Comment: Did not work "MINDATEDIFF" not a built-in function name

Comment: That should have been `min(datediff(...))`.

Comment: Also, I've changed the query since my original post, I had this portion reversed. I need to take the min time out and subtract it from the max time in (this is assuming they took a break).  For example.  If I punch in at 7am, leave for break at 11AM then back at 11:22AM I took a 22min break.  I need to do that math, and then report the exception

Comment: Changing to min(datediff(...)) produces the same results as my query above.